# Unable to read file from spring boot .jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, path, resources

I want to access file on my classpath called `reports/invoiceSweetChoice.jasper` in jar on production server. Whatever I do I get null.

I have tried `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("reports/invoiceSweetChoice.jasper")`, tried via `InputStream` etc. I have printed out content of `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` and it is empty. Not sure how is that possible. Do you have any suggestion how to resolve this ?

Comment: It seems to be different for jars. Does this help (section 5)? https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: In your jar's manifest.mf, what's your classpath?

Comment: Have a look at the spring [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html) interface. You can autowire it. And you probably want to put the file in the src/main/resources directory.

Comment: @HopeyOne file is in src/main/resources/reports/ folder. Could you please explain what did you thought with ResourceLoader class ?

Comment: @hd1 manifest does not have that info. How to define it ?

Comment: Please see my answer, @laban007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In manifest.mf, the classpath is defined using the [class-path key and a space-delimited list of files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), as follows:

MANIFEST.MF at root of jarfile.

```
Class-Path: hd1.jar path/to/label007.jar path/to/foo.jar
```

If there are spaces in the jar filename, you should enclose them in quotes.

If it's a webapp, the reports path should be in your BOOT-INF subdirectory of your classpath -- this is automatically performed by maven if you put it in src/main/resources in the standard layout.

EDIT:

Now that you've clarified what you're trying to do, you have 2 approaches. Like I said above, you can grab the file from the BOOT-INF subdirectory of your webapp or you can enumerate the entries in the jar until you find the one you want:

```
JarInputStream is = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream("your/jar/file.jar"));
JarEntry obj = null
while ((obj = is.getNextJarEntry()) != null) {
   JarEntry entry = (JarEntry)obj;
   if (entry.getName().equals("file.abc")) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByetArrayOutputStream(); 
        IOUtils.copy(jarFile.getInputStream(entry), baos);
        String contents = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
        // your entry is now read into contents
   }
}
```

Comment: this is when reading from some other jar? But this file is in jar that I'm running. If jar is named test.jar do I need to add Class-Path : test.jar even if MANIFEST.MF and the file that I want to read are in that jar ?

Comment: Only if they are in external jars. If the class is included in the jar, you needn't. If it's in an embedded jar, you will need a custom classloader.

Comment: File is in the jar. Hmm...I need a custom classloader? How to do that? And why do I need it, why it does not load in normal way ?

Comment: Which jar? The one you're running or is it embedded within the jar?

Comment: File is in jar that I'm running.

Comment: Yes, it is in BOOT-INF/classes but not sure how to grab it, tried a lot of approaches, tried getClass().getResourceAsStream, tried with resourceLoader etc. Do you have a suggestion ? I need to get InputStream object. Example that you gave is missing jarFile instance.

Comment: Ok, this worked for me. But I'm still confused why classLoader or resourcLoader didn't work.

Comment: If you want to investigate further, let's do so on chat here.

Comment: Hmm, i did that and i have found out that some files in .jar were corrupted. Not sure how did that happen, but when i recompiled jar i got it working with loaders. Really really weird problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Autowired private ResourceLoader resLoad;


void someMethod() {
    Resource r = resLoad.getResource("classpath:reports/file.abc");
    r.getInputStream()...
    ...
```

Comment: I got java.lang.NullPointerException. And I have checked, I got my file in that folder

Comment: Does the reports directory with the file exist in the jar? Should be in BOOT-INF/classes/

Comment: Yes, it's there. This is a web app if that matters. And I'm running it with java -jar jarFile.jar. Am I missing some weird server configuration ?

Comment: I can't find any specific configuration to get this to work in our spring boot jar. There's no classpath in our manifest.

Comment: What version of spring-boot are you running?